# How do I convert from old symbol to new ruby 1.9 hash syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, morris.js

I'm using morris.js to display charts in my application. In my controller I have the code:

**controller**

```
@users_count = User.group('DATE(created_at)').count.map do |d, c| {date: d, count: c} end
```

From this I get:

```
[{:date=>'2013-04-01', :count=>1}, {:date=>'2013-04-02', :count=>1}]
```

When I try to pass this to morris.js as a data option it doesn't work. I need to convert this to:

```
[{date: '2013-04-01', count: 1}, {date: '2013-04-02', count: 1}]
```

Then it works.

How can I do that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with old vs new hash syntax. You cannot convert output to the new syntax. It will always use the old syntax. What morris expects is probably a JSON string. You can get it by using `.to_json`. So, Arjan's answer is correct. This is the explanation his answer lacks.

Comment: Thanks @Mischa. I updated my anwser with your explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with old vs new hash syntax. You cannot convert output to the new syntax. It will always use the old syntax. What morris expects is probably a JSON string. You can get it by using .to_json.

Use `to_json` on your result and pass that to morris.

```
@users_count = User.group('DATE(created_at)').count.map { |d, c| {date: d, count: c} }.to_json
```